# Measure time between submits in Flask

Tags: python, flask, time

I would like to measure time a user needs to take a decision (or just pressing the "submit" button in this case). In the python itself I normally measure the time of code with

```
start_time = time.clock()
time_diff = start_time - time.clock()
```

However, in the web application I can't wrap my head around how it should work.

```
@app.route('/survey')
def main():
    user = request.cookies.get('user')
if not user:
    return redirect(url_for('login'))
    msg = ''
    word = request.args.get('word')
    score = request.args.get('score')
start_time = time.clock()
if score:
    time_diff = start_time - time.clock()
    record_to_csv(user, word, score, time_diff)
return render_template(
    'main.html',
    self_url=url_for('main'),
    word=choice(words),
    msg=msg,
)
```

My first idea was just to put start_time before "if score" and then measure the time right after. But somehow I always get the same time of -4.10546782348e-07. So I wonder if the problem is that I fail to put the time measurement on the right place in the loop or if it is a completely wrong approach. Any comments are very appreciated.

Comment: When you say `measure time a user needs to take a decision` are you saying `when the page is fully loaded in I should start the timer` or `when user clicks on X element to start the timer`? Basically, at a design prospective where do you want to start your timer ?

Comment: @MooingRawr First time the difference between when the page is fully loaded and the click on the submit button. But if it is hard then I could also skip it, because it is the first one. And then as soon as submit is clicked the user gets another word to evaluate so the timer should sort of start and finish with submit.

Answer (score 0):

You can hold `start_time` in session, and check it after post request was made:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        time_diff = time.clock() - session.get('start_time', 0)
        print time_diff

    session['start_time'] = time.clock()
    return render_template('index.html')
```

Otherwise this verable will be lost after every request.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. I am not sure, isn't the session - the whole time the users is answering the questions and not just the time between questions? Sorry, I don't really understand it properly. But basically if I put the start_time outside of the whole thing, then it will not get lost after the request. So I then just need to calculate the difference to the previous time stamp.

Answer (score 0):

So I've put the start time measurement outside, and I measure the difference after "if score". Like this I get the cumulative time, this is why I always subtract the time of the previous step. Seems to work. And I have also changed the function time.clock() to time.time().

```
start = time.time()
previous_difference = []
previous_difference.append(0)
@app.route('/survey')
def main():
    user = request.cookies.get('user')
if not user:
    return redirect(url_for('login'))
    msg = ''
    word = request.args.get('word')
    score = request.args.get('score')
start_time = time.clock()
if score:
    diff = end - start
    time_diff = diff - previous_difference[-1]
    previous_difference.append(diff)
    record_to_csv(user, word, score, time_diff)
return render_template(
    'main.html',
    self_url=url_for('main'),
    word=choice(words),
    msg=msg,
```

)